# DropDown Menu applying to all buttons instead of one

Tags: javascript, html, css

The Recipes button should open a dropdown menu with 2 items, I've managed to add the menu but it displays on its right, also any button opens the dropdown menu even tho the class and id are set alone.
Here is the full website code: https://pastebin.com/AjhJWhr8

Below is the buttons code I added for the menu dropdown, sorry about the mess..

```
<div class="button-group special" id="dropdown">
        <button onclick="window.location.href='Home.html';"     class="button HomeButton"><span><b>Home</b></span></button>
        <button onclick="OpenRecipes()" class="button RecipesButton" id="dropbtn"><span><b>Recipes</b></span></button>
        <div class="recipes-content">
            <a href="ApplePie.html"><b> Apple Pie </b></a>
            <a href="BananaPie.html"><b> Banana Cream Pie </b></a>
        </div>
        <button onclick="window.location.href='Terms.html';"    class="button CookTermsButton"><span><b>Cooking Terms</b></span></button>
        <button onclick="window.location.href='Diet.html';"     class="button CookDietButton"><span><b>Cooking Light Diet</b></span></button>
        <button onclick="window.location.href='Contact.html';"  class="button ContactButton"><span><b>Contact Us</b></span></button>
    </div>
```

As you see in the screenshot below the menu opens even if I click on the diet button (highlighted in blue on hover).

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5rtM.jpg)

Comment: I got the problem and solution but your code is quite messed up and complicated!! You are new to `html` or coding??

Comment: You have not provided enough code for people to be able to assist you with your issue. HTML is just markup, it has nothing to do with the overall logic that you're describing. Your issue could be CSS and/or JS based. None of your JS is included in the pastebin that you provided. Also, since this looks very simple in its essence, try replicate the issue in a sandbox (either in a snippet here, or codepen or similar).

Comment: @KunalTanwar Yes I'm studying that in university newly, i had to search everything up cause teachers don't assist us sorry

Comment: @Martin I have the whole page code in the pastebin link

Comment: instead of paste bin paste your code here. Also your `js` file is not available in your pastebin link.

Comment: If all the code is in the pastebin, why is this function, `OpenRecipes()`, not defined anywhere? It's being called in 2 places, but there is no trace of a definition of this function. This is what leads me to 1) Believe code is missing, or 2) You added a bunch of copy paste code blocks without actually realizing what it's doing / how it's working.

Comment: I did not use js yet, it's not working I've got to look into that after fixing the buttons

Comment: Yes the code isn't all my writing as I said in the first comment I did not get taught those stuff so I had to search multiple things up and try to apply them, it was going good until I got to the dropdown menu part.